using adb : check the underlying version of a service
I am trying to get information about the composer3 system service using adb shell.
I can use this command to list the service
service list | grep -i composer
this show me the android.hardware.graphics.composer3.IComposer/default service is running.
console:/ # service list | grep -i composer  
1      SurfaceFlinger: [android.ui.ISurfaceComposer]  
2      SurfaceFlingerAIDL: [android.gui.ISurfaceComposer]  
34     android.hardware.graphics.composer3.IComposer/default [android.hardware.graphics.composer3.IComposer]

I'm using Android U, where two versions of android.hardware.graphics.composer3 are defined -
android.hardware.graphics.composer3-V1-ndk and android.hardware.graphics.composer3-V2-ndk.
I have included android.hardware.graphics.composer3-V2-ndk in my build.
Is there a way to check which version of composer3 is being included from the adb shell ?
